# How can I run Android Studio (Android SDK Emulator) in Windows 10 Home edition?

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v

I want to learn android and I installed Android Studio and create an emulator from Android Emulator Manager and later I got that my windows 10 is Home edition and it does not have Hyper-V option though I enabled Virtualization technology from Bios. But Android Emulator cannot recognize it and telling me to turn on the VT. I am unable to run the emulator. How can I run the emulator?

Thank you.

Comment: A workaround I would use here would be to not use the emulator at all, but rather just test your app directly from your Android phone.  As Marvin Gaye famously sang `Ain't nothing like the real thing`.

Comment: That's not possible. My phone is very old.

Answer (score -1):

HAXM, the Intel Android Virtualization Technology is incompatible with Hyper-V. Turn off Hyper-V and give it a go again. Hyper-V will often be installed if you have installed Visual Studio with Windows Phone tools.

Or from an admin command prompt run the following. Note to get an admin cmd prompt, right-mouse the windows icon, click Command Prompt (Admin ).

To turn off Hyper-V run this: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off and then reboot

To turn Hyper-V back on, run this: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto And then reboot

You can turn off Hyper-V in the services menu (type "Services" in the Search thingy), and also use the Services menu to turn it back on. Even though it may not be necessary I still reboot after doing it this way.

Blog post on this here - http://www.devfish.net/post/2015/08/18/error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration-android-on-windows.aspx

Comment: I don't have Hyper-V option at all. I have windows 10 home edition. it does not support hyper-v option.